# How to create a group of equations?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

To solve all the a[i,j] & b[i,j] through Mathematica,I need to create a group of equations.The m & n are arbitrary.And for all the 0<=i<=m & 0<=j<=n,the equations should be estabished.
The equations:

```
a[i-1,j-1]+b[i,j-1]==a[i-1,j]+b[i-1,j-1];
a[i,j]+b[i,j]==a[i-1,j]+b[i,j-1]+P[i,j];
P[x1,y1]==t;
P[x2,y2]==-t;
else P[i,j]==0;
a[-1,x]==0,
a[m,x]==0,
b[x,-1]==0,
b[x,n]==0
```

（the x here is arbitrary)

Comment: Wrap them in a list `{eq1, eq2, ...}` or link them with the logical `And` operator (`&&`) as `eq1 && eq2 && ...`.

Comment: @MarcoB Thanks,but my question is that I need that the equations could be simply changed when I change  m or n,for example,if i want to m=3 &n=2,I need to create a group of equations,but when i change n from 2 to 4,I need to create a different group again

Comment: @MarcoB Could you please give me a method to create a group of equations automaticly?I mean that I just need to type in m & n,and the program can change  i & j and give out the equations(or the result of`Solve[]`) itself

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is this what you want?

First we write all equations that do not depend on i or j. Then we make a list with all equations that depend on i and j. Then we join the 2 lists. For a small example we choose n=m=2:

```
n = 2; m = 2;

eq1={P[_, _] == 0,
     P[x1, y1] == t,
     P[x2, y2] == -t,
     b[x, n] == 0,
     a[-1, x] == 0,
     a[m, x] == 0,
     b[x, -1] == 0}

eq2= Table[{a[i - 1, j - 1] + b[i, j - 1] == a[i - 1, j] + b[i - 1, j - 1],
   a[i, j] + b[i, j] == a[i - 1, j] + b[i, j - 1] + P[i, j]}
  , {i, 0, m}, {j, 0, n}] // Flatten;

eq=Join[eq1,eq2]
```

Comment: Thanks very much,your answer is quite beautiful! I haven't imagine the function `flatten` could be used in this situation.

Comment: And I have a small question still,how to make all `P[i,j]==0` except P[x1,y1] & P[x2,y2]

Comment: Sorry,I mean that how to put 0 to all `P[i,j]`,that is`P[i,j]=0`, rather than `P[i,j]==0`

Comment: You can achieve this by specifying: `P[_,_]=0` . Now, do not think that this will set all `P[.,.]=0`. Instead MMA applies more specific patterns before more general ones. If you specify a more specific pattern like `P[1,1]=2` MMA will try first this pattern before the more general one. Note, I changed my answer to include this case

Comment: Thanks,the method is right.However,before I change x1,x2 or y1,y2,I must close the document and reopen it,or MMA will let both the former and the new `P[x1,y1]=t;P[x2,y2]=-t`,could you let just the new P = t or -t?Here is my code`m =; n =; x1 =; y1 =; x2 =; y2 =;
P[_, _] = 0;
P[x1, y1] = 1;
P[x2, y2] = -1;
b[_, n] = 0;
a[-1, _] = 0;
a[m, _] = 0;
b[_, -1] = 0;Solve[Table[{a[i - 1, j - 1] + b[i, j - 1] == 
      a[i - 1, j] + b[i - 1, j - 1], 
     a[i, j] + b[i, j] == a[i - 1, j] + b[i, j - 1] + P[i, j]}, {i, 0,
      m}, {j, 0, n}] // Flatten] // Flatten`

Comment: Note: `m=;` is not proper syntax, probably you mean `m=.`(note the dot)  to clear some variable. But there is an easier way to clear all variables defined earlier by you in one go : Clear["Global`*"] (note the back tick).  Note further, somebody changed all the "set" characters: `=` in my answer to "equal": `==`. Now, it depends what you need. If you want  equations, that is correct. However, if you want to give a variable a value, e.g. setting P[1,2] to 1, then you need "set" characters. I let it stand for the moment as I am not sure what you need. Have fun.